# I am probably Locking my SQL Server Table by running a SELECT and INSERT and SELECT concurrently

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 that holds "positions" for different companies.

I have a function GET_KEY that creates a position number by performing a SELECT MAX over the table. [I can not use Identity Increment because the position number needs to be the first available number for a particular company]

```
SELECT @v_position_no = max(POSITION_NO) + 0.01 
FROM POSITIONS WHERE COMPANY_NO = @p_company_no
```

I have a function that copies a position `COPY_POS`.

I want to copy an existing position twice, but to assign each position an appropriate position number.

I run `GET_KEY`, then `COPY_POS`, then `GET_KEY`, then `COPY_POS`

However, the positions table locks.  I am almost positive (and it is logical) that this is because there a conflict between `GET_KEY` and `COPY_POS`. [The problem only occurs if I try and do `GET_KEY` and `COPY_POS` twice in succession]

---

**What I tried...**

1. I tried encasing each of `GET_KEY` and `COPY_POS` in a `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN`, but this didn't work.
2. The entire stored procedure is contained in a `BEGIN TRY` and `END TRY` and I tried removing this, but this also didn't work...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `WITH (nolock)` to the Select statement!

```
SELECT @v_position_no = max(POSITION_NO) + 0.01 
FROM POSITIONS WITH (nolock) WHERE COMPANY_NO = @p_company_no
```

Comment: ... as long as you can live with the fact that now you might be getting **non-committed** rows into your `SELECT` result set - data that might never really end up in the database...

Comment: You might want to consider `WITH (READPAST)` (omitting non-committed rows) as an alternative.